# upload multiple images from local drive into site

Tags: asp.net, image, file, image-uploading

I want to provide facility to my users to upload multiple images into my website using asp.net 2.0, using single file uploader i.e. want to upload all the image file from a folder. Or suggest me any alternate way.

Answer (score 1):

This is not yet possible in (X)HTML.

- [HTML5](http://rakaz.nl/2009/08/uploading-multiple-files-using-html5.html) will support it, and some browsers already have a working implementation, but it's still a draft and not widespread (Firefox 3.6+ and Webkit only at the moment);
- [SWFUpload](http://swfupload.org/) is a common alternative but it requires Flash.

Answer (score 0):

- using pure HTML you can only upload single files. This is how HTML is structured. The file upload tag only takes a file, not a folder. Security reasons.
- You may want to look at Silverlight / Flash for a control allowing upload of a folder.

Answer (score 0):

[swfUpload](http://swfupload.org/) is really nice. And although it is flash it degrades very nicely to HTML upload if flashnot installed.